# Run ADB Shell script when more than one device is conncected

Tags: android, adb

I have one login script written to login to my device, when multiple devices are connected, how to run that script in particular device.

login.sh

```
adb shell input text abc@def.com
adb shell input keyevent 61
adb shell input text abc123
adb shell input keyevent 61
```

Answer (score 0):

When multiple devices are connected you can retrieve the list with `adb devices` :

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
017296d5904c        device
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

Then, you can target a particular device by using the `-s` option :

```
adb -s 017296d5904c shell input keyevent 61
```

[source](http://codetheory.in/execute-adb-commands-query-particular-android-device-emulator/)

The final step is to iterate on your devices list with a for loop and run your commands.

Comment: this is for adb shell command, i have a script(login.sh) written with some adb shell commands, i need to run that script